# Is it common practice to symbolic link to the GOPATH folder?

Tags: git, go

My git projects are stored here:

```
~/dev/git/project1 ...
```

I am starting a golang project, and since it requires using the GOPATH is it common practise to create a symbolic link from my projects git path to GOPATH?

Comment: I also symlink into GOPATH for each project, but do not put any symlinks *inside* GOPATH; the Go tools purposely don't follow them when resolving dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Because of dependency issues between packages, symlinking was used for the GOPATH. The structure of [GOPATH](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable), however, always suggested that it was to be used for multiple projects and symlinking your `GOPATH` has been discouraged by the go developers.

In the latest version (1.6), however, they finalised a solution to the dependency problem (experimentally introduced in 1.5), in the form of a folder named `vendor/` placed at top level of your package ([link](https://blog.golang.org/go1.6)). This folder will be searched before the regular `GOPATH` for package used by import statement.

There are various tools to use to streamline the dependency process like [godep](https://github.com/tools/godep) or [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide), making using the `vendor/` folder a lot less time-consuming than symlinking the `GOPATH`. Using a vendor package is also better reproducible than symlinked dependencies, ensuring your package will work for everyone.

So I would encourage you not to symlink your GOPATH, and use this newly introduced standard.

Comment: I don't symlink my gopath. I symlink my package to my gopath. And I use vendor in my project as well.

Answer (score 1):

What I end up doing is instead created my own `GOPATH` within a go project I want to keep isolated to my normal global `$GOPATH`.

I make a '`b`' script (at the root folder of the project) which:

- check if `src` exists (in the project folder, here in `~/dev/git/project1`): if not it creates it;
- check if src/mypackage exists: if not, if creates the symbolic link `src/mypackage -> ~/dev/git/project1`.
- is called with an alias: `alias b='. ./b'`

That way, the same '`b`' (short for 'build') goes into `~/dev/git/project1/src/mypackage`, and does a `go install`.
If you have a `main` package, that will create a binary in `~/dev/git/project1/bin`.

That way, each of my go project remains autonomous, not lost in a sea of other go packages in my normal `$GOPATH/src`. I reserve the global `$GOPATH` for global projects that helps me to develop in go: `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...`, `github.com/fzipp/gocyclo` and the likes (other linters).

---

In other words, **I do not symlink `GOPATH`**.
I do symlink my package inside my project to a local `GOPATH` (local to said project), but the GOPATH itself is a fixed folder (again specific to my project), defined as usual, without any symlink)

And that is perfectly compatible with the [vendor folder](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories) for vendoring source dependencies.

---

```
alias b='. ./b'
cd /path/to/my/project
b:

#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -e src ]; then mkdir src ; fi
if [ ! -e src/myproject ]; then ln -s /path/to/my/project src/myproject; fi
cd src/myproject
go install
cd ../..
```

Comment: Can you share this 'b' script of yours?  Is this a batch script?

Comment: @coolbreeze yes, simple bash script which makes a `ln -s`, a `cd` and a `go install`, nothing too fancy, but enough to make my go project compile anywhere I want.

Comment: @coolbreeze I don't have it in my current environment (Windows), but I'll edit the question with (from memory) the general idea